# How can I enable text copying functionality within an email using handlebars as an email template?

Tags: javascript, nestjs, handlebars.js

I am working on an application that sends emails using Nest.js, and I'm facing a challenge with enabling text copying functionality within the email content. I have an HBS template that includes a paragraph of text and a button with an onclick function to copy the text when clicked.

However, when I receive the email and test the button, I find that the onclick function is not present in the button within the email client. I understand that email clients have limited support for executing JavaScript code, but I'm wondering if there's an alternative approach or workaround to achieve the desired text copying functionality within the email.

I have already considered using a  element to display the text, but I would like to explore other possibilities if available. Is there a way to achieve this using query selectors or any other method within the constraints of email client limitations?

Any insights, suggestions, or alternative solutions to enable text copying within an email would be greatly appreciated.